# How to get cell value of date and time type of an excel file using Java?

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel file where one column contains date and time in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format.
I want to read them and found that excel file can be read in java using apache-poi. But I failed to get those value.
 How can I obtain those value?

Comment: can you past some code?

Comment: view my posted solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which cell i.e. column position, in each row is going to be a date.

Then you can get it via `row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue()` .

[getDateCellValue()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getDateCellValue%28%29)

For more generic cases [find out here](http://www.dbunit.org/xref/org/dbunit/dataset/excel/XlsTable.html)

Also know about how to read and write in excel files using POI.jar [here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html)